# Stars and string combination pattern in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I want a pattern like: 
Input : Python is Interactive (any string separated by space)
Expected Output:

```
    *************
    *Python     *
    *is         *
    *Interactive*
    *************
```

I tried using python's "re" module ,not able to create the stars in the pattern

```
    inp = "Python is interactive"
    import re

    split = re.split(' ', inp)
    length = []
    for item in range(len(split)):
        length.append(len(split[item]))

    Max = (max(length))

    for i in range(len(split)):
        print(split[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `re` module. Your approach is not that bad, but needs some rework:

```
  input = "Python is interactive"

  parts = input.split(" ")

  maxlen = max(map(lambda part: len(part), parts))
  # or this, if you want to go even more elegant:
  maxlen = max(map(len, parts))

  print ('*' * (maxlen + 4))
  for part in parts:
      spaces = maxlen - len(part)
      print("* " + part + (" " * spaces) + " *")
  print ('*' * (maxlen + 4))
```

For splitting you can use the string.split method. Then I calculate the maximum length (like you did, but a little bit more elegant).
Then I print as many stars as the most long string is + 4 because at the beginning and end of each string there is "* " and " *", so 4 more characters.
Then I print the string with as many spaces as padding as needed.
Finally the last line of stars.